# Ruby on Rails with RSpec and shoulda-matcher validate_inclusion_of giving NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, authlogic, shoulda

I'm having problems with the validate_inclusion_of matcher when writing a spec.

My current specs are to do with users and user groups. A user has a user group id.

**I want to check that the user group id of a user is actually in the list of current user group ids.**

At the moment my spec is basically:

```
describe 'company_user_group list of valid IDs' do
  let!(:company_user_group_everything) { FactoryGirl.create(:company_user_group_everything) }
  let!(:company_user_group_nothing) { FactoryGirl.create(:company_user_group_nothing) }
  it '' do
    @company_user = FactoryGirl.create(:company_user, id: 1)
    CompanyUser.current_id = @company_user.id

    is_expected.to validate_inclusion_of(:company_user_group_id).in_array(CompanyUserGroup.full_list_of_ids)
  end
end
```

but the error I get is:

```
    1) CompanyUser validations company_user_group list of valid IDs should validate that :company_user_group_id is either ‹2› or ‹3›
         Failure/Error: is_expected.to validate_inclusion_of(:company_user_group_id).in_array(CompanyUserGroup.full_list_of_ids)

         NoMethodError:
           undefined method `attribute_setter' for nil:NilClass
```

I have tried various different things and debugged using byebug etc. but nothing is working for me.

e.g.

Adding in

```
    @company_user_group_id = @company_user.company_user_group_id
```

and changing the is_expected.to line to

```
    is_expected.to validate_inclusion_of(@company_user_group_id).in_array(CompanyUserGroup.full_list_of_ids)
```

I get the following error

```
  1) CompanyUser validations company_user_group list of valid IDs should validate that :8 is either ‹8› or ‹9›
     Failure/Error: is_expected.to validate_inclusion_of(@company_user_group_id).in_array(CompanyUserGroup.full_list_of_ids)

     Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel::AllowValueMatcher::AttributeDoesNotExistError:
       The matcher attempted to set :8 on the CompanyUser to 8, but that
       attribute does not exist
```

So it seems that the group id to check is valid (e.g. 8) and the array is valid (e.g. 8 and 9) but the matching isn't working.

Any help much appreciated!

Some of the company user model

```
    # This model holds User identities for internal staff.  This model is
    # primarily intended for use in the xxxx application.
    class CompanyUser LT ActiveRecord::Base
      acts_as_authentic do |c|

        c.merge_validates_uniqueness_of_email_field_options case_sensitive: false
        c.merge_validates_length_of_password_field_options minimum: 8

        if Rails.env.production?
          c.logged_in_timeout = 30.minutes
        else
          c.logged_in_timeout = 90.minutes
        end
      end

      # Constants

      # relationships
      belongs_to :company_user_group

      # validations
      validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
      validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
      validates :company_user_group_id, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
      validates :company_user_group_id, inclusion: { in: CompanyUserGroup.full_list_of_ids }, unless: 'Rails.env.test?'
      validate :check_sys_admin_permission
```

If the "unless: 'Rails.env.test?'" bit is removed, most of the specs fail for some unknown reason. Just mentioned in case it is relevant.

and the following method from the Company Group model

```
      # class methods
      def self.full_list_of_ids
        CompanyUserGroup.all.pluck(:id)
      end
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're actually testing as well as the test please.

Comment: As in some of the company model?

Comment: Yes, and also `CompanyUserGroup.full_list_of_ids`

Comment: Ok, although I did try just using a plain array at one stage in place of full_list_of_ids and that didn't help, but will add in the original question. Thanks.

Comment: I have added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. For some reason the validate_inclusion_of works when it is within a let! block.

It doesn't matter what argument is sent to the let helper method, just that one is.

Still don't know WHY this fixes it though, if anybody can enlighten me!?

So, the following spec now passes

```
    describe 'company_user_group list of valid IDs' do
      let!(:company_user_group_everything) { FactoryGirl.create(:company_user_group_everything) }
      let!(:company_user_group_nothing) { FactoryGirl.create(:company_user_group_nothing) }

      let!(:temp) do
        it {is_expected.to validate_inclusion_of(:company_user_group_id).in_array(CompanyUserGroup.full_list_of_ids)}
      end

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
it '' do
  @company_user = FactoryGirl.create(:company_user, id: 1)
  @company_user.company_user_group = company_user_group_everything

  expect(@company_user).to validate_inclusion_of(:company_user_group_id).in_array(CompanyUserGroup.full_list_of_ids)
end
```

You might not even need to set the company user gropu of the company user.

But you've got

```
validates :company_user_group_id, inclusion: { in: CompanyUserGroup.full_list_of_ids }, unless: 'Rails.env.test?'
```

Which surely means it would fail because you don't do that in the test environment

Comment: Alas same error

 1) CompanyUser validations company_user_group list of valid IDs should validate that :company_user_group_id is either ‹8› or ‹9›
     Failure/Error: expect(@company_user).to validate_inclusion_of(:company_user_group_id).in_array(CompanyUserGroup.full_list_of_ids)
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `attribute_setter' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I then removed the ", unless: 'Rails.env.test?'" bit in the model, but many other specs fail and the error for the above spec changes to

CompanyUser validations company_user_group list of valid IDs 
     Failure/Error: @company_user = FactoryGirl.create(:company_user, id: 1)
     
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Company user group is not included in the list

Comment: I should also point out that in factory girl, when a user is created, the group id of the first row is assigned and if that doesn't exist, a new group is created and that id assigned to the user. i.e. company_user_group_id   { (CompanyUserGroup.first || FactoryGirl.create(:company_user_group)).id }

Comment: What line is `undefined method attribute_setter for nil:NilClass` erroring on?

Comment: The is_expected line: "is_expected.to validate_inclusion_of(:company_user_group_id).in_array(CompanyUserGroup.full_list_of_ids)" OR the expect line: "expect(@company_user).to validate_inclusion_of(:company_user_group_id).in_array(CompanyUserGroup.full_list_of_ids)" if that's in there instead. When "subject.inspect" is outputted, that contains just a blank user, if that's relevant. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like an issue with [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/904)